# I cannot figure out why getView() method cannot run correctly when I reuse View component

Tags: android, baseadapter

I defined a Adapter which extends `BaseAdapter` when I use `ListView` to display something.I overrided `View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method to reuse View component, in the method, I also wrote `if(convertView == null) {System.out.println("test");}` block. There are 50 rows data in `ListView` and the screen only can display about 20 rows data.    when I ran the application, LogCat printed less than 50 rows of "test" though I slided the screen to make sure all data are loaded.But why ? I think it should print 50 rows data. Here is the key code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        System.out.println(++count + "convertView == null:" + convertView);
    } 
}
```

someone help me please, I am a newbie.... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `convertView` will be `null` only if there isn't a previously returned view that can be recycled (i.e. it's no longer on screen).

The views you return from an adapter's `getView()` can be recycled in later calls to `getView()`. The framework passes such recyclable views in via the `convertView` arg.

So your `convertView == null` branch only gets run enough times to fill the listview screen once and after that, when scrolling, these old views get recycled.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not inflate a View for every item in your adapter. It reuses inflated views previously used for **other** items.

The pattern for binding views in a adapter is something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if(convertView == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    // bind data to view here
    return view;
}
```

In fact you normally would use a ViewHolder class. But first fix your basic adapter before reading about that.

Answer (score 0):

You missing `return view`.

ListView recycles view. [How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

Use a `ViewHolder` pattern

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ViewHolder holder;
  if(convertView == null) {
     convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
     holder = new ViewHolder();
     holder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);   
     //initialize views
     convertView.setTag(holder);  
  } else {
     holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }
  // update your view here
  holder.tv.setText("hi");
  return convertView;   
}

static class ViewHolder {
  // YourViews Declaration
  TextView tv; // an example 
}
```